# Python: run "try" again after exception caught and worked out

Tags: python

Is there any way to enter try statement once again after catching the exception in the first try? 
Now I'm using "while" and "if"  statements and it is making the code messy. 
Any ideas? 
Will try to simplify it as possible, sorry that have no logic...

```
run = True
tryAgain = True
a=0
while run:
try:
    2/a
except Exception:
    if tryAgain:
        tryAgain = False
        a = 1
    else:
        run = False
```

Comment: You are looking to try at most one more time, and if it fails that one more time, raise an exception?

Comment: One or more (it is based on ssh connection and it can take several trys)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try using a `break` statement in your `try` block:

```
while True:
    try:
        # try code
        break # quit the loop if successful
    except:
        # error handling
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering you are doing this in a `while`, then you can make use of `continue` to just continue back to the beginning of the while loop:

```
tryAgain = True
a=0
while True:
    try:
       2/a
       break # if it worked then just break out of the loop
    except Exception:
        if tryAgain:
            continue
        else:
            # whatever extra logic you nee to do here
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using a `for` loop so that the trying and trying doesn't go on forever. Then the loop's `else` clause is a place to put the "I give up" code.  Here is a general form that will support 'n' retries > 1:

```
a=0
num_tries = 5
for try_ in range(0,num_tries):
    try:
        2/a
    except Exception:
        print("failed, but we can try %d more time(s)" % (num_tries - try_ - 1))
        if try_ == num_tries-2:
            a = 1
    else:
        print("YESS!!! Success...")
        break
else:
    # if we got here, then never reached 'break' statement
    print("tried and tried, but never succeeded")
```

prints:

```
failed, but we can try 4 more time(s)
failed, but we can try 3 more time(s)
failed, but we can try 2 more time(s)
failed, but we can try 1 more time(s)
YESS!!! Success...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python, so this may not be best practice. I returned to the try statement after triggering the exception by lumping everything into a single function, then recalling that function in the except statement.

```
def attempts():
    while True:
        try:
            some code
            break #breaks the loop when sucessful
        except ValueError:
            attempts() #recalls this function, starting back at the try statement
            break
attempts()
```

Hope this addresses your question.